# AMPL: selecting variable matrix indices to be integers

Tags: variables, integer, ampl

If I declear var x {1..3}; is there a way to specify specific indices to be integer variables?

i.e. x[1] & x[3] are integer variables while x[2] is continuous.

```
var x{1..3}; 
x[1] integer;
x[3] integer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically indexed variables are all integer or all continuous, but you can do that by having another indexed variable (e.g., `y`) that is integer and using a constraint to enforce `x[2]` and `x[3]` to be equal to integer variables (e.g., `y[2]` and `y[3]`) as follows:

```
var x{1..3};
var y{i in {1, 3}} integer;
s.t. xinteger{i in {1,3}}: x[i] = y[i];
```

The constraint `xinteger` ensures `x[1] = y[1]` and `x[3] = y[3]`. Since `y` is integer, `x[1]` and `x[3]` must be integer too.